# How many squares can fit in a circle without going outside the perimeter?

Tags: geometry, optimization, packing-problem

How many squares of side length $x$ can fit in a circle of diameter $n\cdot x$, where $n$ is any positive number, such that none of the squares overlap the perimeter of the circle and all of the squares are aligned in a grid (i.e. no zig-zagging of edges)?

For example:
[image]
This is for a project I'm doing using Excel, so it'd be ideal to have a formula, versus an infinite series or a c++ function.

Thanks!

[Edit]:  Some folks have suggested [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3007527/how-many-squares-fit-in-a-circle) but I think that only works when the circle is very large (relative to the squares).  For example, a circle of 3x gives a result of 0.4, when clearly (from the image above) you can fit 4 squares inside.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many squares fit in a circle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3007527/how-many-squares-fit-in-a-circle) If you search the web for square packing in a circle you will find several links that might be useful.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I don't know of any exact formulas, but for large $n$ the answer will be $\approx \frac{\pi}{4} n^2$, and the approximation gets better and better for larger and larger $n$. Indeed we're really approximating the area of a circle of radius $\frac{nx}{2}$ by squares of width $x$, and so the number needed will be roughly the ratio of their areas.

Comment: Even if you want the squares aligned in a grid, you can fit 7 squares into the circle with diameter $4x$, by moving your rectangle a bit left and adding another square to the middle right of the rectangle.

Comment: See Misha's suggestion and may be we could be even more aggressive. Any limitation on square positions?